# Show PopUp from serevr side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

SHOW Popup Error when click LinkButton I have No Idea how to solve this issue?

PopUp

```
        <%--popupBind function--%>
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function OpenPopUp() {
        debugger;
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
</script>
<%--end--%>
<%--  PopUp Code--%>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content" style="width: 55%;">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" CssClass="patient-detail"></asp:Label></h4>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblservicename" runat="server" CssClass="patient-detail" Style="color: green; font-size: 16px;">
                                    Header
                                </asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnProcess" runat="server" Text="Start" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnpending" runat="server" Text="Waiting" CssClass="btn btn-default"/>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnclr" runat="server" Text="Completed" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
<%--end--%>
```

Button (Click On Button for Open PoPuP)

```
 <asp:Button OnClick="Unnamed_Click" ID="popup" runat="server" />
```

Button Event On Server Side

```
protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dQuery = "";
    string DCode = Convert.ToString(Session["DCode"]);

        dQuery = @"SELECT * FROM TABLE";
    DataTable dtButton = obj.GetDataTable(dQuery);
    rptButtonMaster.DataSource = dtButton;
    rptButtonMaster.DataBind();
  //  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "OpenPopUp();", true);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, Page.GetType(), "success", "<script> OpenPopUp(); </script>", false);
}
```

When Click On Button (Call Javascript Function)

```
 <script>
    function OpenPopUp() {
        debugger;
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
</script>
```

Getting All the time same error on Load
**Error** : Model is not a function

What am I missing??

Comment: where do you call `OpenPopUp`?

Comment: from server side   ------                                                                                       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, Page.GetType(), "success", "<script> OpenPopUp(); </script>", false);

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your call into a document ready statement

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, Page.GetType(), "success", "<script>$(function(){OpenPopUp();})</script>", false);
```

Make sure the script is registered/loads after the bootstrap and jquery libraries